# Ada + Machine Learning (Python Framework)

Tags: machine-learning, ada

I'm trying to write a simple machine learning application in Ada, and also trying to find a good framework to use. My knowledge of one thing is extremely minimal, and of the other is somewhat minimal.

There are several nifty machine learning frameworks out there, and I'd like to leverage one for use with an Ada program, but I guess I'm just...at a loss. Can I use an existing framework written in Python, for instance and wrap (or I guess, bind?) the API calls in Ada? Should I just pass off the scripting capabilities? I'm trying to figure it out.

Case in point: Scikit (sklearn)
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#

This does some neat stuff, and I'd like to be able to leverage this, but with an Ada program. Does anyone have advice from a similar experience?

I am just researching, so I have tried finding information.

http://www.inspirel.com/articles/Ada_Python_Binding.html
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#

Comment: Is this on Linux or Windows or something else?  There are different python packages which will work with other languages, depending on operating system.

Comment: Windows 10. So I'm looking for something that will run on Windows 10, core program in Ada, but that can tap into python.

Comment: There are several methods - pipes, ctypes, cffi and RPCs.  Each one has its own advantages and disadvantages.  You probably need to try each one in turn and decide which one is easiest for you.

Comment: I switched over to possibly just doing an Interface to C using Tensorflow. But...still kind of floundering on a basic example, because of the learning curve.
Case in point: just trying to call TF_Version from Ada is...challenging.

Answer (score 0):

The inspirel solution is based on python2.7.  If you're using anything from python3.5 onwards a few mods need to be made.  On Linux, changing to say python 3.7, you'd just change

```
--for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-lpython2.7");
for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-lpython3.7");
```

but on windows, the libraries aren't dumped in a community lib so gnat doesn't know where to find them.  All the packages are kept separately.  The -L has to be added to tell the linker where to find the library.  Alternatively, you can use **for lib_dir**.  In my case, I did a non-admin install of python, so it looks something like

```
for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-L\Users\StdUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\libs", "-lpython37");
```

Note that on windows, the library is called python37: not python3.7.  Use gprbuild instead of gnatmake -p, which has been deprecated.  If you do all your mods correctly

```
gprbuild ada_main.gpr
```

should give you an executable in obj\ada_main.exe if it builds.  If a later version of python is used, some edits need to be made

python_module.py

```
#print 'Hello from Python module'
print('Hello from Python module')

#print 'Python adding:', a, '+', b
print('Python adding:', a, '+', b)
```

ada_main.adb

```
-- Python.Execute_String("print 'Hello from Python!'");
Python.Execute_String("print('Hello from Python!')");
```

Some routines have been deprecated so the linkage has to change

python.adb

```
--pragma Import(C, PyInt_AsLong, "PyInt_AsLong");
pragma Import(C, PyInt_AsLong, "PyLong_AsLong");

--pragma Import(C, PyString_FromString, PyString_FromString");
pragma Import(C, PyString_FromString, "PyUnicode_FromString");
```

Running the build and executable should give

```
C:\Users\StdUser\My Documents\ada-python>gprbuild ada_main.gpr
Compile
   [Ada]          ada_main.adb
Bind
   [gprbind]      ada_main.bexch
   [Ada]          ada_main.ali
Link
   [link]         ada_main.adb

C:\Users\StdUser\My Documents\ada-python>obj\ada_main.exe
executing Python directly from Ada:
Hello from Python!

loading external Python module and calling functions from that module:
Hello from Python module!

asking Python to add two integers:
Python adding: 10 + 2
Ada got result from Python: 12

we can try other operations, too:
subtract: 8
multiply: 20
divide  : 5
```

Remember to put the pythonxx.dll somewhere on your path otherwise it won't be able to find the library when it starts executing.